# MessageGroupStoreReaper what exactly is it for

Tags: spring-integration

All spring projects have extensive and extremely helpful documentation and the same is the case for spring integration project but one topic that I want able to gather much information on is message group reapers. Basically it seems like it's a mechanism that can influence an aggregator externally to release some messages. What is unclear is How different or similar it is from a release policy. Does it actually releases messages from aggregator so they are then processed by subsequent components in the flow or it just empties out the aggregator kind of like discarding the aggregated messages. Secondly is there control over which messages are released so messages that belong to a particular group are released but not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to Spring Integration 4.0, the aggregator was a completely passive component. Group release (or not) is triggered by the arrival of a new message - when the release strategy is consulted to see if the group to which the message belongs can be released. So, how do we discard (or release) a group that is idle and has had no new messages arrive for some time?

The reaper runs on a schedule and can detect "stuck" groups and release them based on time without a new message arriving.

It is also used to remove empty groups - the aggregator can be configured so that empty groups remain present so that late arriving messages can be discarded instead of forming a new group. Empty groups can be reaped on a different schedule to partially complete groups.

The reaper expires all groups that meet the configured criteria; if the group passes the criteria, it is expired; otherwise it is not, and will be considered the next time the reaper runs. The action taken by the reaper (partial release, discard etc) depends on other settings on the aggregator.

Spring Integration 4.0 introduced new attributes (`group-timeout` and `group-timeout-expression`), allowing partial groups to be released automatically after the timeout, without a reaper (the timer is armed when a new message arrives for a group). The reaper can still be used to expire (remove) empty groups in this case.

I hope that explains the function of the reaper.

Comment: Thanks that helps. I am still unclear about how exactly to specify this criteria on the message reaper to specifically release some group. In a release policy it makes sense because RP is invoked for every incoming message and the group it releases is based on which message it returned true for. But since reaper is an external component how can you specify the group criteria on it. A small example might be helpful. The new attributes `group-timeout` and `group-timeout-expression` seem extremely helpful. Looking forward to webinar on SI 4.0.

Comment: There's an example in reference manual (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper). In that case, it runs every 10 seconds with a timeout of 30. I think you are over-thinking it; see the javadoc for the `timeout` property (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/store/MessageGroupStoreReaper.html#setTimeout(long)). The reaper runs every so often and, if any group is older than the timeout, it is forced complete. The timeout is counted from when the group was created (default) or last updated.

Comment: Okay makes sense. One last question, so can the group-timeout property be configured to look at the idle activity (time since last message arrived) instead of group creation time (time since first message arrived). I dont see anywhere in jdocs about the former.

Comment: The `group-timeout` *does* trigger from the last message arrival (not group creation time). It cannot be configured to use group creation time. For the reaper, the default is group creation time, but can be configured to use the last modified time instead. There is no such choice with `group-timeout`, it is always based on last message arrival.

Comment: great so group-timeout is for idle activity which is perfect. Thanks